POI: get formula for Row reference as named reference
So, I'm trying to get formula for row reference e.g. (=2:2 / =Sheet1!2:2 etc.) that is referenced via named range e.g. test_row
If I use getAddress method for cells it works correctly, but if I define named range e.g. test_row with adress =Sheet1!2:2 and try to acess it's formula via namedRange.getRefersToFormula() I get Sheet1!1048576:1048576. On the other hand, same case for column reference =A:A with named range test_col works properly.
I haven't looked into source code of POI lib, so I can't say whether it's prolem with lib or the way Excel safes formulas for row references.
The question is whether somebody faced that problem and found some workaround?
UPD: thanks to @AlexRichter, I found out that everything described above works for absolute addresses e.g. =$2:$2 or =Sheet1!$2:$2
The question remains why it doesn't work for relative addresses?
Tests were conducted with:
poi: 5.2.5 
poi-ooxml: 5.2.5
poi-ooxml-schemas: 4.1.2
openjdk 21.0.2


Why does the name not refers to =Sheet1!$2:$2 instead of the relative =Sheet1!2:2? If relative the refers-to changes if active row changes. Using the absolute reference =Sheet1!$2:$2 it works independent on what active row is set.

@AxelRichter, your point was indeed right! At first, I thought that: yeah it works the way you described, but how does that relate to the problem described in the original question? But when I tested with an absolute address, the function indeed returned the correct address.
I'm still not sure why it doesn't work with relative addresses, but such solution works for me for now. I'll update the original question and if no further ideas appear I will close it with this workaround.
Thanks!

Named ranges usually are set to refer to absolute relations. That is =Sheet1!$2:$2 instead of the relative =Sheet1!2:2 for example. Named ranges which refer to relative relations have strange behaviour.
If one sets a named range to refers to =Sheet1!2:2 while a cell in row 3 is the active cell, then this named range refers to =Sheet1!2:2 only if a cell in row 3 is the active cell. If a cell in row 2 is the active cell, then this named range refers to =Sheet1!1:1. And if a cell in row 1 is the active cell, then this named range refers to =Sheet1!1048576:1048576. Excel stores what the named range refers to when cell A1 is the active cell. So it stores =Sheet1!1048576:1048576. And this is what you get.
The absolute reference =Sheet1!$2:$2 is independent of the active cell. Thus a named range which refers to =Sheet1!$2:$2 will always refer to that reference.
